# AWS NLog: Updating the AWSTarget.LogStreamPrefix to modify the Cloudwatch streamname at runtime

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, nlog

AWS target just decides not to log anything after making the code changes to update its streamname.  Leaving it alone it will log normally, but if I do what I have put in code below it kicks the bucket and does not log anything to cloud watch and also does not exhibit errors when modifying the NLog.config to internalLogToConsole="true"

Here is an easy to use example repo, if you have aws creds locally it should work off the shoot, well it will work if you don't do the random modification to LogStramName [GitHub Repo Sample](https://github.com/cartermq/AWSLoggerPrefixAtRuntimeIssue/blob/master/AWSPrefixAtRuntimeIssue/AWSPrefixAtRuntimeIssue/Program.cs)

**NLog.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true" internalLogToConsole="true">
  <targets>
    <target name="aws" type="AWSTarget" logGroup="ForumHarvester" region="us-east-1"/>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Console" layout="${callsite} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile,aws" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Nuget Dependencies:

- NLog
- AWS.Logger.NLog

**The Code which entirely breaks the awstarget rather than renaming its stream**

```
if (filekey != string.Empty)
            {
                var config = NLog.LogManager.Configuration;
                var awstarget = config.FindTargetByName("aws") as NLog.AWS.Logger.AWSTarget;
                awstarget.LogStreamNamePrefix = filekey.Replace("--", "-id:") + "---";
                NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config; //Its implied that this will reload the configs
                // and all will be right with the world, thats not my experience so far

                 //NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers(); 
                 // I was also trying this because it looks promising but no dice
            }
```

**Debugging on Log**

Here is a sample of what I get with internal logging on:

```
2020-07-22 07:30:27.4953 Info Auto loading assembly file: C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.AWS.Logger.dll
2020-07-22 07:30:27.5796 Info Loading assembly file: C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.AWS.Logger.dll
2020-07-22 07:30:27.6157 Info NLog.AWS.Logger, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604. File version: 1.5.2.0. Product version: 1.5.2. GlobalAssemblyCache: False
2020-07-22 07:30:27.6717 Info Auto loading assembly file: C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.AWS.Logger.dll succeeded!
2020-07-22 07:30:27.6717 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2020-07-22 07:30:27.7137 Info Adding target AWSTarget(Name=aws)
2020-07-22 07:30:27.7226 Info Adding target ConsoleTarget(Name=logfile)
2020-07-22 07:30:27.7721 Info LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true can crash the application! Use only for unit-testing and last resort troubleshooting.
2020-07-22 07:30:27.7721 Info Validating config: TargetNames=logfile, aws, ConfigItems=17, FilePath=C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.config
2020-07-22 07:30:28.1910 Info Configuration initialized.
2020-07-22 07:30:28.1910 Info NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.7.2.11786. Product version: 4.7.2+024896f64b840a743d3fd89e29c2186681e7795f. GlobalAssemblyCache: False
2020-07-22 07:51:49.1766 Info Closing old configuration.
2020-07-22 07:51:49.2775 Info Validating config: TargetNames=logfile, aws, ConfigItems=17, FilePath=C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.config
2020-07-22 07:51:49.2775 Info Validating config: TargetNames=logfile, aws, ConfigItems=17, FilePath=C:\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.config
...Application.Program.Main --IN MAIN--
...Application.Program.Main MAIN ARGUMENTS: -c interactive -a Application --tt false --filebucket jobs
```

--IN MAIN-- Never appears in cloudwatch, but it is obviously on the screen/console log.

Reference Materials:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code , https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues/83 , https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues/1

Comment: Maybe enable the NLog InternalLogger and check the output: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Yea I did do that i thought within the config.  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true" internalLogToConsole="true">  Which does start showing logging but I dont see any exceptions or obvious errors.

Comment: Added the slightly anonymized internal logging to the question.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Updated this a bit, wonder if I should just address it on the AWS github or the main NLog one?  You seem pretty versed based on your other post activities.

Comment: It is strange that NLog InternalLogger shows the re-initialization, but not any errors. Without any error messages or exception stacktraces, then it is difficult for any party to guess what the current problem is. You are welcome to create an issue for the AWS-project, but I think you will be on your own.

Comment: Haha yes perhaps.  Looks like I get to fix it myself probably if its possible.